# AttributeError: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'append'

Tags: cupy

What am I doing wrong?

```
x = cp.array([1,3,5])
x = cp.append(x,1)
x


AttributeError: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'append'
```

https://docs.cupy.dev/en/v9.0.0a2/reference/generated/cupy.append.html#cupy.append

Comment: I assume you did `import cupy as cp`, right?

Comment: Yes I did imported it.

Comment: Could you show `cupy.__version__`?  `cupy.append` is from v9.0.0a1.  https://github.com/cupy/cupy/pull/4112